# UICollectionView Cell width

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    print("WIDTH = \(frame.width)")//shows 320
    return CGSize(width: 155, height: 160)
}
```

I have a manually made collectionView and in it I manually initialize cells, which must be shown in two columns. Here it should looks by logic

```
return CGSize(width: frame.width/2, height: 160)
```

but when width is greater than 155, it shows in one column. What is this 5 pixels? How can I make it show in two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try check the gap between cells at "Min Spacing". In storyboard you could check in "Size Inspector"

[image]

Comment: thanks       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.0
    }